Android Studio Iguana New UI Font Rendering Problem
I am experiencing a font rendering issue in Android Studio Iguana where the code is rendered incorrectly. This problem occurs on both Mac (with M1 chip) and Windows platforms. Below is my environment setup:

Android Studio Version: Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2
Build: #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11668458, built on April 4, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+7-b1000.50 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
OS: macOS 14.3.1
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering: ON

Registry Settings:

ide.browser.jcef.sandbox.enable=false
ide.experimental.ui=true

Attached are screenshots for comparison between the old UI and new UI font display.
Screenshot of the Old UI font rendering
Screenshot of the Old UI font rendering
Screenshot of the New UI font rendering
Screenshot of the New UI font rendering
Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any suggestions on how to fix it?
I have tried reinstalling Android Studio, changing the boot java runtime version, uninstalling all plugins, but nothing has fixed the rendering issue.

Just uncheck this checkbox "Use color scheme font instead of the default":
Color Scheme Font
